How to change the parent window of a CoreWebview2 in winui 3
I am working on WindowsAppSDK(winui3) 1.6 . Which should be able to configure the enviorment of webview2 according to Microsoft learn. I have to change the parent window of the Webview2 that I already created because I did something like "drop the tab outside of the current window to create a new window." like this:
private void Tabcontrol_TabDroppedOutside(TabView sender, TabViewTabDroppedOutsideEventArgs args)
{
    sender.TabItems.Remove(args.Tab);
    App.AddNewWindow().Tabcontrol.TabItems.Add(args.Tab);
}

I set the Tab' parent to the tabview in a new window. But the ParentWindow of the CoreWebview2Controller seems to be the old window. Because when I clicked on the Webview2 control, old window will come to the top. And if I close the old window ,webview2 just disappeared.
This is the .GIF of what happened. I clicked on the bottom window which is created by the App.AddNewWindow() above and the first window came to the top.
I saw this document CoreWebView2Controller.ParentWindow Property but I don't even know how to set it because there is no CoreWebview2Controller property in Webview2.CoreWebView2. I think it should be set when await ensureCoreWebview2Async() function is called for the first time.
